# Confused about Html.AttributesFor(m => m.Name))

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to learn from the code of others. I saw the following:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, Html.AttributesFor(m => m.Name))
```

Can someone explain to me how the Html.AttributesFor works? What kind of attributes are these and where can I set them up.

Update:

I found the following hidden in the code:

```
  public static IDictionary<string, object> AttributesFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
        {
            var attributes = new RouteValueDictionary {{"class", ""}};

            WhenEncountering<StringLengthAttribute>(expression, att => attributes["maxlength"] = att.MaximumLength);
            WhenEncountering<HintSizeAttribute>(expression, att =>
                {
                    attributes["class"] += att.Size.ToString().ToLowerInvariant() + " ";
                });

            attributes["class"] = attributes["class"].ToString().Trim();
            return attributes;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextBoxFor` helper has three overloads and no one specifies the syntax as you have posted, may be its a custom helper somebody has written for convenience. The second argument of `Html.TextBoxFor` takes html `objectHtmlAttributes` which you can specify like

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.name,new { @class="classname", @rel="nofollow" })
```

or it takes a `IDictionat<string,object>htmlAttributes`

Comment: Where do you explain what `AttributesFor` does?

Comment: @jgauffin its a custom helper how can i be sure about what it does apparently it specifies the html attributes for the said editor

Comment: Yeah it looks like a custom helper. After I saw that comment I went and looked around more. Not quite sure how it works but I included a sample to show the helper.

Comment: @Melissa i'll advice you to place a break point inside the helper and proceed step by step.